# Hyphen between letter and number

Tags: regex, string, java-6, replaceall

I need a function to put a hyphen where letters finish and numbers start or when numbers finish and letters start, for example, `1234GRR` to `1234-GRR`.

I am using Java 6.

I have this, but this just puts a hyphen everwhere.

```
public static String addHyphen(String word) {
    StringBuilder longer = new StringBuilder(word.substring(0,1));
    for (int i = 1; i < word.length(); i++) {
      longer.append("-" + word.charAt(i));
    }
    return longer.toString();
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: The community here usually expects to see the results of your previous research and where your own attempt at a solution, following that research, failed. This allows us to avoid offering ideas you have already tried.

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how to tell the function to put a hyphen when the next position changes to number or letter.

Comment: a hint for you `unicode`

Comment: you don't have any conditional logic in your code. How is this supposed to know where to put the hyphen if it never does any checks with an if statement?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution would be to use a regex, assuming of course that you know regex. To locate a place between two characters, we use `(?<=X)` zero-width positive lookbehind and `(?=X)` zero-width positive lookahead.

```java
public static String addHyphen(String word) {
    return word.replaceAll("(?i:(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z]))", "-");
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(addHyphen("1234GRR1234GRR"));
```

*Output*

```
1234-GRR-1234-GRR
```

---

For full [Unicode definition](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) of "letters" and "numbers", use this regex instead:

```java
"(?<=\\p{L})(?=\\p{N})|(?<=\\p{N})(?=\\p{L})"
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(addHyphen("1234FooⅯⅭⅭⅩⅩⅩⅣḞõô"));
```

*Output*

```
1234-Foo-ⅯⅭⅭⅩⅩⅩⅣ-Ḟõô
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check `word` for `null` in  `addHyphen` to avoid `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash No. Well, not for me to decide if a `null` value is allowed. The question code doesn't allow it, so I'm going with that (very common) decision.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static String addHyphen(String word) {
          boolean words=false;
          boolean number=false;
          String end=new String();
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                if (word.substring(i,i+1).matches("[1-9+]")&number==false){
                    number=true;
                    words=false;
                    end=end+"-"+word.substring(i,i+1);
                }else if (word.substring(i,i+1).matches("[a-zA-Z]")&words==false){
                   number=false;
                   words=true;
                    end=end+"-"+word.substring(i,i+1);
                }else {
                    end=end+word.substring(i,i+1); 
                }
            }
            return end.substring(1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regex arguments as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String[] testStrs = { "1234GRR", "GRR1234", "Hello", "Hello1234World", "1234GRR1234GRR" };
        for (String s : testStrs) {
            System.out.println(addHyphen(s));
        }
    }

    public static String addHyphen(String word) {
        String str = null;
        if (word != null) {
            str = word.replaceAll("([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)", "$1-$2");
            str = str.replaceAll("([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)", "$1-$2");
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1234-GRR
GRR-1234
Hello
Hello-1234-World
1234-GRR-1234-GRR
```

Note: `$1` and `$2` refer to the first and second [capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) respectively.